# Standard PHP File Includes

Tags: php, bootstrapping

Is there any standard php files that should be included like bootstrap and a config file? These files are extremely useful, are there any other best practice files?

Comment: There's no "standard" php includes. There's only includes that you need: your libraries, or external libraries that you've opted to use. Dno't go with a kitchen sink approach and include EVERYTHING regardless of your needs. it's a waste of resources.

Comment: Maybe this question was too broad and opinionated, however i learned about bootstrap long after hearing about php, i was just wondering if there was something i may of missed?

Comment: @JackTrowbridge I'm still confused why are you talking about boostrap, php and boostrap have nothing to do with one another.

Comment: Right okay i have a greater understanding now, i get that bootstrap is just a term used to describe a file you include at the start, and that's the same with the config file. However what i am trying to ask is there anything like the 'bootstrap file' and the 'config file' even though there are not php specific; are there other files like this that and regarded as standard is some ways.

Comment: @salivan, "bootstrap" in this context likely refers to setup scripts, settings, etc. as in "get the application started", not to the CSS/JavaScript framework from Twitter.

Answer (score 2):

You can "extend" PHPs functionality by using PHP libraries or PEAR.

## Loadable libraries (aka Extensions)

Loadable libraries is a only true native way to extend PHP. To use libraries you have to download source code and compile it yourself, or download distribution-based libraries.

Every library should exactly match your PHP version and build options.

These libraries are useful for connecting to database, implementing encryption, image manipulation and other core tasks.

Example of such a libraries are:

- For windows: php_pdo.dll, php_gd.dll;
- For linux: php_pdo.so, php_gd.so;

Every library provide additional functionality: classes, constants, functions.

You can obtain many libraries from PECL - PHP Extension Community Library.
More here: http://pecl.php.net/

There are two possible ways to load an extension: via php.ini files or via dl() function call. dl() have potential security (and not only security) issues, so is disabled in most cases.

## PEAR

Another technique frequently used in PHP is PEAR - **PHP Extension and Application Repository**.

PEAR is a framework and distribution system for reusable PHP components. It contains additional (essential) implementations of almost anything you can imagine.

This is opensource repository with dozens of ready to use libraries, extensions and components.

More here: http://pear.php.net/

Comment: Composer/Packagist is worth mentioning too

Comment: Yes, composer is not bad thing, but it is outside of standard scope I think. This is a third-party dep manager.